# How can I match case with shapeless variable?

Tags: scala, shapeless

How can I match case with shapeless variable ?

Let's say I have variable of following type `shapeless.::[String,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]]`

Currently I have to do this

```
authHeaders.hrequire(shape_value => {
    val (client_id, client_secret) = value.tupled
    isAuthorized(client_id, client_secret)
  }
  )
```

Can I somehow unwind `String :: String :: HNil` to String pair so that I don't have to do it in separate statement ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is method `unapply` in object `shapeless.::`:

```
def unapply[H, T <: HList](x: H :: T): Option[(H, T)]
```

So you could just match on `HList` like this:

```
scala> val ::(a, ::(b, HNil)) = "1" :: "x" :: HNil
a: String = 1
b: String = x
```

Or with alternative syntax for `unapply` method with `Tuple2` result:  `a :: b` instead of `::(a, b)`:

```
scala> val a :: b :: HNil = "1" :: "x" :: HNil
a: String = 1
b: String = x

scala> "1" :: "x" :: HNil match {
     |   case a :: b :: HNil => s"$a :: $b :: HNil"
     | }
res0: String = 1 :: x :: HNil
```

In your case:

```
authHeaders.hrequire{
  case client_id :: client_secret :: HNil => isAuthorized(client_id, client_secret)
}
```

**Alternative**

You could use `tupled` method to convert function of N arguments to function of single `TupleN` argument.

For function:

```
val isAuthorized: (String, String) => Boolean = ???
authHeaders.hrequire{ isAuthorized tupled _.tupled }
```

For method:

```
def isAuthorized(s1: String, s2: String): Boolean = ???
authHeaders.hrequire{ (isAuthorized _) tupled _.tupled }
```

Comment: Absolutely awesome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: To match type you can do: `case (a: String) :: (b: String) :: HNil => s"$a :: $b :: HNil"`